# Kohana PHP question

Tags: php, kohana

I have a database with a table named `shoppingcarts`. this table has the following 3 columns:

```
id, sessionid, date
```

I have a function (`AddProductToCart`) in my controller (`ShoppingCart`). Inside my function, I have this call:

```
$obj = ORM::factory('shoppingcart')->where('sessionID',session_id())->find();
```

Now, this statement runs against the `shoppingcarts` table and returns a row which has the `sessionid` matching the current session id (PHP's `session_id()`).  But sometimes, the `sessionid` does not exist in the table.

So, how do I check the value returned by that statement to make sure that a value was returned or not?

I'm confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the property 'loaded'. [Docs](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/orm#loaded)

It would look something like this:

```
$obj = ORM::factory('shoppingcart')->where('sessionID',session_id())->find();

if($obj->loaded == TRUE)
{
  // user has a shopping cart
}
else
{
  // no shopping cart found
}
```

Comment: Ambirex,

thanks for the answer. I had been looking for this property for so long. i was even tempted by the idea of iterate through all rows in the table and comparing them with the session_id() returned value, and then setting a boolean flag to true if the session_id() existed already.

You saved my day !